# Run query into php

Tags: php, sql

I´m trying to run this query into php but I´m not able to make it, and don´t know what´s exactly wrong with the code.
query is running fine if I run it through phpmyadmin.
Please let me know what is wrong in it.
Thanks

```
<?php
$username = "cp";
$password = "aasfadasd";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("smj",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select examples");
  $query = "UPDATE rot_galls JOIN rot_grs SET rot_galls.name = rot_grs.name WHERE(rot_galls.rgroup = rot_grs.id";
$result=mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: typo here WHERE(rot_galls.rgroup  ?

Comment: It's always a good idea to provide an error message. However, the typo thing should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do not use mysql, it is deprecated use mysqli or better PDO.

2) your query has a typo. You forgot to close the bracket.

```
 "UPDATE rot_galls JOIN rot_grs SET rot_galls.name = rot_grs.name WHERE(rot_galls.rgroup = rot_grs.id)";
```

Comment: yes the problem was the final bracket. Thx guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem

```
WHERE(rot_galls.rgroup = rot_grs.id
```

you are missing a closing bracket. Change it to this

```
WHERE(rot_galls.rgroup = rot_grs.id)
```